# Include both COUNT(*) and Sum(X) in a single async query Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ASP.NET MVC project I'm trying to achieve the equivalent of this SQL Server code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalCount, SUM(SomeColumn) as TotalSum 
FROM SomeTable
WHERE param1 = 'foo' AND param2 = 'bar'
```

...with Entity Framework in a single async query. Essentially I'm looking to get not only the sum, but also the number of rows used to calculate the sum of the `SomeColumn` column in a single call.

So far I've only managed to do this in two calls:

```
using (var context = new myEntities())
{
    // 1st query which does .SumAsync(x => x.SomeColumn)
    // 2nd query which performs a .Count() on the result set
}
```

Is it possible to do this in one async call, like the SQL provided above? Should I just create a view or stored proc on the SQL side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var query = await (from zz in db.SomeTable
                       where zz.Foo > 1
                       group zz by 1 into grp
                       select new
                       {
                           rowCount = grp.CountAsync(),
                           rowSum = grp.SumAsync(x => x.SomeColumn)
                       }).ToListAsync();
```

I tested a sync version in a dev environment I am running.

Comment: Any "Where" criteria you wish to use

Comment: this is the right approach when `group by 1` (some constant), so the whole will be put in just 1 group.

Comment: @KingKing thanks, how would the `group by 1` part look like in the chaining syntax? `.GroupBy(x => 1)` ?

Comment: @globetrotter what do you mean? to get count and sum of the whole, it is obvious that the whole should be put in just 1 group. So the the group key should be constant (for all), we can choose any constant value other than 1.

Comment: @globetrotter ah yes, you edited your comment, the method syntax is `.GroupBy(x => 1)`

Comment: thanks, i converted it to use the chaining syntax and it works great

Comment: Should that be a `ToListAsync()`?  Shouldn't this be a `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Yes the way the query is written `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Tested with **EF Core 6.0**

The following **LINQ** query:

```cs
await Table.GroupBy(_ => 1, (_, rows) => new
           {
              Count = rows.Count()
              Sum = rows.Sum(x => x.Column),
              Average = rows.Average(x => x.Column),                  
           })
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Will be translated to the following **SQL** query:

```sql
SELECT TOP(1)
  COUNT(*) AS [Count]
  SUM([t].[Column]) AS [Sum],
  AVG([t].[Column]) AS [Average],     
FROM[Table] AS [t]
```

Answer (score -2):

It's really not necessary to call SumAsync on the IQueryable. The following will give you the query you want in the way you want it:

```
            var foo = from item in context.Items
                      group item by item.ID into grp
                      select new
                      {
                          Value = grp.Sum(f => f.ID),
                          Count = grp.Count()
                      };
            await foo.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: this results in multiple records while the OP's query returns just 1 record, how could this be equivalent to that?

Comment: Grouping by ID here is plainly wrong. It's useless. Each group has 1 item.